# Building WebRTC on specific branch heads

Tags: android, webrtc, chromium

WebRTC Doc described a lot of information, including work with Release branches. But as far, we cannot build WebRTC on specific branch-heads. For example building latest WebRTC changes already described, but in other cases, we should do:

```
cd /path/to/webrtc/src
gclient sync --with_branch_heads
git fetch origin
```

After we have all Chromium Release branches. For example now, We want to build WebRTC on Sprint Release: remotes/branch-heads/55. We do checkout, configuring build and running:

```
export GYP_DEFINES="OS=android"
gn gen out/Default --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'
```

This takes only 2 seconds, and generate some files in out/Default directory, but sure, there are no libraries. But if we did commands above on latest master changes, everything build successful.

So what is the correct way, to build WebRTC on specific branch-heads? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It was by bad. With using local untracked changes. After hard reset and gclient sync, everythings goes Ok.

Answer (score 1):

first, I don t think you need the GYP_DEFINES anymore, then, gn will only generate the build files but not build. You need to call "ninja -C out/Default" to actually build the libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I just think this is problem, because in master latest changes, this takes much more time. After calling "ninja -C out/Default" everything goes correct.